# Isolated zero $z$ of $X$ on a star shaped polygon.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, vector-spaces

Consider a polygon that is star shaped with respect to the isolated zero $z$ of $X$. I want to show that the boundary of the polygon can be made transverse to $X$ by jiggling vertices only in the radial direction. The point being is that after the jiggling, we still get a polygon that is star shaped.

I am not sure exactly what is wants me to do here. Maybe the wording is confusing to me. I do understand that by doing what it says above we will start with a star shaped polygon and end with a star shaped polygon. I dont know how to do all the inbetween detail though.

Comment: What is $X$? Without knowing that, we have no way to know what you are asking.

Comment: I believe $X$ is a general vector field